# Get the value of input after the div is click

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have this table row in the table

```
<tr>
    <th>
        <input type="text" id="ismall" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0">
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" id="imedium" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0">
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" id="ilarge" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0">
    </th>
    <th>
        <input type="text" id="ixlarge" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0">
    </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="4" style="padding: 0px">
        <div class="add-to-cart" onclick="addToCart()">Add to pizza cart</div>
    </th>
    </tr>
</tr>
```

When I click the `add-to-cart` I will alert the data what is inside of `ismall`, `imedium`, `ilarge` and `ixlarge`. But I was not able to get the value using JavaScript.

How can I do it?

My **JavaScript**:

```
function addToCart(){
    alert(document.getElementById('ismall').value);
}
```

Comment: div ?? why don't you use button ??

Comment: @BhaveshGangani so I can style it easier.

Comment: You can also style buttons..  even a button is recommended for such kind of purpose.

Comment: Use a form with a submit listener, it will make it very much easier to collect the input values and sort out the order. Also, if the client–side script fails, you can fallback to standard form behaviour. You are going to have to send data to the server anyway, a form makes that simple.

Comment: it is working when i tested by placed it in plain html file

Answer (score 0):

The code working is correctly. However, You should use `Number()` function to convert string into numerical value. eg,

```
function addToCart(){
    alert(Number(document.getElementById('ismall').value));
}
```

HTML + Javascript **[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/f5usp9rr/)**.

I'm suggesting you to put your javascript at the bottom of the page instead of in `<head>` tag. eg. put javascript just before closing `</body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

I recommended to you to use button for the click, but anyway that is not the problem. Also that again I recommended to you to `addEventListener` for events. Your javascript

```
document.getElementsByClassName('add-to-cart')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
  alert(document.getElementById('ismall').value);
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/0w3j94sf/1/

That works, but your code I think also should be work. You have a placeholder in your inputs, witch is 0. And that is not a value. If you click the button and you are not set the value of input the result of alert will be empty. You must set on inputs the attribute `value="0"` if you wont to have default value.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine check my fiddle

[**Js Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/or064kbz/)

```
function addToCart() {

    a = document.getElementById('ismall').value
    b = document.getElementById('imedium').value
    c = document.getElementById('ilarge').value
    d = document.getElementById('ixlarge').value

    alert(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c + ' ' + d);
}
```

if the fields are empty it will give blank alert

Answer (score 0):

Try this [live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/t7mjkgop/2/)

```
<form id=pizzaForm >
        <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="ismall" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0" autofocus required>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="imedium" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0" required>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="ilarge" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0" required>
        </th>
        <th>
            <input type="text" id="ixlarge" maxlength="2" size="2" placeholder="0" required>
        </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4" style="padding: 0px">
            <input type="submit" value="Add to pizza cart"  id="continue_btn" class="add-to-cart"/>
        </th>
        </tr>
    </tr>
</form>
```

Js

```
function addToCart(){
    allIput.forEach( function(e){
       alert(e.value);
    });
}

var allIput =Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("input[type=text]")),
 highlightForm = document.querySelector("#pizzaForm");

highlightForm.addEventListener('submit',addToCart , false);
```